# Add a bookmark to a PDF with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm trying to add a bookmark to a PDF using PyPDF2. I run the following with no problems. But a bookmark is never created. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong. The PDF is 2 pages long.

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

reader = PdfFileReader("test.pdf")  # open input
writer = PdfFileWriter()  # open output
writer.addPage(reader.getPage(0))  # insert page
writer.addBookmark("Hello, World Bookmark", 0, parent=None)  # add bookmark
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding bookmarks using PyPDF2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855907/adding-bookmarks-using-pypdf2)

Comment: @ShubhamNamdeo that question, doesnt help; theres an error in the answer

Comment: do the bookmarks depend on the previous added pages? Can they be added at any moment, for example also at the end when all pages are already added?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ran your code (*adding the text below it to write out the pdf*) and found a bookmark was, in fact, created.

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

writer = PdfFileWriter()  # open output
reader = PdfFileReader("test.pdf")  # open input
writer.addPage(reader.getPage(0))  # insert page
writer.addBookmark("Hello, World Bookmark", 0, parent=None)  # add bookmark
with open("result.pdf", "wb") as fp:  # creating result pdf JCT
    writer.write(fp)  # writing to result pdf JCT
```

Check the bookmarks panel in your result.  Having bookmarks doesn't automatically cause a PDF to open to the bookmarks panel.

To make it open to the bookmarks panel with PyPDF2, add one line:

```py
writer = PdfFileWriter()  # open output
reader = PdfFileReader("test.pdf")  # open input
writer.addPage(reader.getPage(0))  # insert page
writer.addBookmark("Hello, World Bookmark", 0, parent=None)  # add bookmark
writer.setPageMode("/UseOutlines")  # This is what tells the PDF to open to bookmarks
with open("result.pdf", "wb") as fp:  # creating result pdf JCT
    writer.write(fp)  # writing to result pdf JCT
```

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated as of 2023. Use pypdf (I'm the maintainer of both projects)

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for James' code. But it only outputs one-page pdf file and doesn't show how to add multiple bookmarks. Here is a revised version of his code to do so.

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

reader = PdfFileReader("test.pdf")  # open input
writer = PdfFileWriter()  # open output

n = reader.getNumPages()

for i in range(n):
    writer.addPage(reader.getPage(i))  # insert page


# add a bookmark on the first page
writer.addBookmark("Hello, World Bookmark", 0, parent=None)

# add a bookmark on the sixth page
par = writer.addBookmark("Second Bookmark", 5, parent=None)

# add a child bookmark on the eighth page
writer.addBookmark("Third Bookmark", 7, parent=par)

with open("result.pdf", "wb") as fp:  # creating result pdf JCT
    writer.write(fp)  # writing to result pdf JCT
```

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated as of 2023. Use pypdf (I'm the maintainer of both projects)