# add keyword based bookmark in pdf in python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to create bookmark in pdf based on keyword present in pdf file. I can create the bookmark for pages in pdf using pypdf2's addbookmark function. but it is   page based, not keyword based.
For example, if pdf contains 'metadata' as a word, I would like to create bookmark for 'metadata' keyword.

I have referred [Add a bookmark to a PDF with PyPDF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546066/add-a-bookmark-to-a-pdf-with-pypdf2?rq=1) which creates bookmark for pages.

```
output = PdfFileWriter() # open output
input = PdfFileReader(open('test.pdf', 'rb')) # open input
output.addPage(input.getPage(0)) # insert page
output.addBookmark('Hello, World Bookmark', 0, parent=None) # add bookmark
outputStream = file('result.pdf','wb') #creating result pdf JCT
output.write(outputStream) #writing to result pdf JCT
outputStream.close() #closing result JCT
```

Comment: Hi ! Could you please past some code you already tried ?

Answer (score 1):

As I think that there is no specific type of bookmark that is what you call a keyword bookmark, perhaps you mean to add a bookmark to every page where the keyword appears. For that you will need to loop over the pages, and if the page contains the keyword, add a bookmark to that page.

Comment: Yes, by this approach I can achieve the end result. but was looking for any library or in build function by which this can be achieved :)